# Get UTC time with DateFormatter in java

Tags: java, dateformatter

I am trying to retrieve UTC time HH:MM:SS using DateFormatter. I can't seem to find a simple example. Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH,mm,ss").withLocale(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

but this code doesn't work. Can someone help me find an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't know about [zoneIds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#:%7E:text=Time%2Dzone%20IDs&text=There%20are%20three%20types%20of,UTC%2B01%3A00%27). It can be done with this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH,mm,ss").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```